# I want to introduce XML into tab! how to do this?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use the latest example "TabLayout" of this http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/android-tutorial-series-layout/

I want to CoffeeShopListActivity to introduce an XML with height of 300dpi.
I created a main XML. then did I put coffee._layout.xml, where inserted text “hello”:

I have main.xml and coffee._layout.xml

I fail. Can you help me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you put a period in coffee._layout, is this a spelling mistake? If so, then your copied and pasted code in the comment on the bottom of that site, has the XML file name wrong.

You need to change this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.coffe_layout);
```

to this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.coffee_layout);
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, please post your code for the XML file, Java file and any errors you are receiving to allow for better troubleshooting.